How to phantom wallet warning sign when interacting with the smart contract
i am building a project on devnet in the solana network and i cant seem to remove the warning sign on my phantom wallet when interacting with the smart contract.
Does anyone have exeperience in this matter?

The alert that you see is coming from Blowfish.
I know it's not perfect, but to get this resolved you should write an email to review@blowfish.xyz telling them about the project and the fact you want to be whitelisted. You'll need to present some socials and if you're not a well known developer in the space, you should get some developers to vouch for you.
